# Can somebody explain the logic of .indexOf() in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

```
function vowelsAndConsonants(s) {
    var vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u'];

    for(let i =0; i<s.length; i++){
        if(vowels.indexOf(s[i]) > -1 ){
            console.log(s[i]);
        }
    }

    for(let j = 0; j<s.length; j++){
      if(vowels.indexOf(s[j]) < 0){
          console.log(s[j]);
      }
    }
}
```

The code above prints out the vowels and then consonants of an input.

I have troubles understanding how `.indexOf()`specifically works in this case.

I understand that `.indexOf()` searches array and returns the position of an element you're looking for, but why does the following condition `if(vowels.indexOf(s[i]) > -1)` only returns vowels?

- To my understanding if `.indexOf()` returns -1 it means that no
  match was found.  In the case, would `if(vowels.indexOf(s[i]) > -1)`
  mean that if a match is found we should execute the code, since it is greater than -1?
- Again, in that case `if(vowels.indexOf(s[j]) < 0)` would then mean
  that if a match is not found execute whatever is inside the if
  statement.

Could somebody kindly explain the logic and give a simple example? I think I'm getting the logic, but at the same time I think I'm not.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It returns the first index of the element in the array or -1 if not found. Full details and example in [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: > -1 is the same as >= 0, the index of a vowel. < 0 is a shorter way of testing for -1 assuming that indexOf won't return any other negative values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`indexOf` function searches in the array of vowels.

If it finds a value it will return it's index, so the result will be greater than -1.

And if it doesn't find it, the result will be -1.

But it's better to use
`if(vowels.indexOf(s[j]) === -1)` instead of
`if(vowels.indexOf(s[j]) < 0)`

Comment: Why is the first example better than the second?

Comment: You will never get a value like -2, -3... the only possible scenario is -1 when there is no match so it's better to be more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you also actually need to know an indexOf result in order to do something with it,  in modern JS it is preferable to use `.includes()` rather than testing against -1 or 0.

`.includes()` is simply more legible

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to use contains(), but it failed since it doesn't work on arrays.